# Creating new lines when writing to a .log file from a php script

Tags: php, logging, newline

I am writing to a .log file called mylog.log from a php script in the following way

```
file_put_contents('mylog.log', "/ntestline");
```

This part of the script is run a number of times. It seems to be writing every entry on the same line and when I run it for two long the log file simply reads.

```
ASCII text, with very long lines
```

How do I add new lines when writing to a .log file from a php script?

Comment: Almost there it's `\n` or `\r\n` if you are on windows

Comment: Also worth noting that file_put_contents will overwrite your log file every time you write it.

Comment: file_put_contents('mylog.log', PHP_EOL . "testline");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) documentations, you can use:

```
file_put_contents('mylog.log',"\r\ntestline",FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 11):

As David Ericsson posted in his commented, you should use the constant `PHP_EOL` as this will insert the correct end of line sequence for the server operating system.

```
file_put_contents('mylog.log', PHP_EOL . "testline", FILE_APPEND);
```

That said, most text viewers/editors can handle either `\n` or `\r\n` - and the more intelligent ones will continue using the same sequence if you further edit the file.

Since PHP is most at home on Linux, I'd recommend using the `\n` if you're not using `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Sill FILE_APPEND is required

Answer (score 0):

To add newlines in plaintext (like a log), use "\n" in your string.
example:

```
$string = "some text \n some more text that will be on a new line";
```

Comment: This option is not scalable, what if the administrator wishes to change operating systems? `\n` isn't supported on all systems